# How can I change onlyOnWeekday(day) with weekday from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events

I can make this example [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/recurrence-rule#onlyonweekdayday) work. What I need is to set the weekday from a cell in column "weekday".

I have tried this:

```
if(type=='PD'){
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekday(weekday);
  event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
}else
```

...where weekday refers to column "weekday".

What am I doing wrong in [my own version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ygk3htjQuqHQKTInlVPV85NoE1zffocxxYWL77t_Z7M/edit?usp=sharing)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could confirm that from your script and shared Spreadsheet, the values of `NewWeekday` are `WEDNESDAY` and `MONDAY` of the string type. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekday(weekday);
event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
```

#### To:

```
var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday[NewWeekday]);  // Modified
event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
```

#### References:

- [Enum Weekday](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/weekday.html)
- [onlyOnWeekday(day)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/recurrence-rule#onlyonweekdayday)
- [setRecurrence(recurrence, startTime, endTime)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series#setrecurrencerecurrence,-starttime,-endtime)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

- You want to use `tstop` as "until".

For this, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekday(weekday);
event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
```

#### To:

```
var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday[NewWeekday]).until(tstop);  // Modified
event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart);  // Modified
```

Comment: Really close :-) The brackets worked. Two things though; 1) The script puts first event on the startdate even if this is not a monday or wednesday. 2) There is no stop :-) Events keep on for years...

Comment: Maybe .times(times) fixed 2).

Comment: @Allan Bech Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `There is no stop :-) Events keep on for years...`, you want to use `tstop` as "until". If my understanding is correct, could you please confirm the added modification? About `The script puts first event on the startdate even if this is not a monday or wednesday.` and `Maybe .times(times) fixed 2).`, I cannot understand what you want to do. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can you explain about the detail of it?

Comment: I can confirm [tstop] works inside .until. Thank you. I also tried .times([times]) and it worked too. Remaining challenge: If I create events for i.e. MONDAYS and WEDNESDAYS on a SUNDAY, the first appearences will be on those sundays.

Comment: @Allan Bech Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `If I create events for i.e. MONDAYS and WEDNESDAYS on a SUNDAY, the first appearences will be on those sundays.`, unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can you provide the detail of it?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. If I create i.e. 4 events to recur on TUESDAYS - and I create them today - then the first instance will appear today end the next three on the following tuedays.

Comment: @Allan Bech Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your new question, for example, **how about adding 1 week for "until" date?** Or, how about adding 1 week to the "start" and "until" date? But I might not be able to still correctly understand what you want to do. So if this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208831/discussion-between-allan-bech-and-tanaike).